# Cannot push branch in git

Tags: git, github, git-push

I'm doing project on Ruby on Rails. Cannot push commits to git, always get this error, when trying to git push :

```
Total 139 (delta 88), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (88/88), completed with 19 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 58c751c4cd45f96f1386eb4f97b40fbf0308ae1434a6617d6c403bd8
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File public/uploads/tmp/1612375485-393249634478175-0006-2847/slack is 126.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/*****
```

I tried to find this file in tmp folder, and delete. But I recieve this error again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete this file from your git repo first of all.

https://devconnected.com/how-to-remove-files-from-git-commit/

Because it has already been stashed and committed.

You can leave it locally if you need (just add it to ignored files after you're done)

Comment: I use "git ls-files" . It doesnt contain this file in list